# iOS set screen orientation programmatically, like method - setRequestedOrientation in Android

Tags: ios, rotation, screen, orientation

Background:
My app was configured in portrait view by default, but for one scene the screen should be in landscape view only.

Question:
How to set the orientation manually with codes, in other words, users need not to rotate the device to generate an event to make the screen rotated.

PS:
I need a method like "setRequestedOrientation" in Android or I need to know how to construct a screen rotation event to send to the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key: 
Use *CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat angle)* from *CoreGraphics*, which could make your view rotated

Sample Codes:

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
  self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
  }

Answer (score 0):

Have you on the desired view controller tried

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Another thing you can do is to change the orientation on the desired view controller from "Inferred" to "Landscape" in the Attributes inspector in your storyboard.

[UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)